# Sort list elements by another list

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have two lists `A[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and `B[6,3,8,2]`. I need to sort the `A` list by `B` list indexes. So that the `A` list will be `[6,8,2,1,4,5,7,9]`. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Tried using java8 streaming and comparators

```java
listB.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(element -> listA.indexOf(element)));
```

But was getting UnsupportedOperationException as listB doesn't have all elements of listA.

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]. I guess, listB is immutable

Comment: Guava has `Comparators.explicit` which might be useful here

Comment: `But was getting UnsupportedOperationException as ListB doesn't have all elements of listA.`  Why should `listB` contain any elements of A?  `ListB` is supposed to contain indexes into ListA?  The only exception I would expect would be an `IndexOutofBoundsException` since 8 would be be an illegal index into A.

Comment: There's no streaming in your code. Also note `element -> listA.indexOf(element)` can be reduced to `listA::indexOf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve performance, the indexes of all the elements in `listB` can be stored in a `Map` first. Then, to order elements that are not in `listB` to the end of the result, they can all be given `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as the sort key.

```java
var listA = Arrays.asList(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9);
var listB = List.of(6,3,8,2);
var index = IntStream.range(0, listB.size()).boxed()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(listB::get, i -> i));
listA.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> index.getOrDefault(x, Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
// listA = [6, 8, 2, 1, 4, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: See the code working [here](https://tio.run/##ZVBNSwMxEL33V@SYSDpo1aotCuvHQWjxUBRBRKa76ZKa3SzJbGmV/vZ1dttDsXOZ8Oa9N2@yxBX2l9l309ii8oHEkgGoyTo4GfeOsEjBYNGOqnrubCpShzGKKdpS/PYE1x6PhMRt5W0mCp7KGQVb5h@fAkMe1Z7c1gqDcDZSIm5FEgJuImCcMCDP9EBf6Es91Ff6Wt@o8ZHmnjUtFfxCDvU5swb/WLbMzJpZzyXNdtkDlrmRp3pnANH@GKkUzP3aZFJB6p0zKcmHXfchAvkpVrKjj0a5IS2s6N8Jqw52dRdA5N9iZVFhQJayWfvku3m9XHeiNg@wyUt4NAusHeO6TWdyE2CavH@9JZPXJ3XoPdtEMgX4mqBiM3JlFybZU7a9bdP8AQ).

Answer (score 0):

`List.indexOf` doesn't throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if the element isn't there, it returns `-1`. So all you need to do is make sure that an index of -1 will result in "somewhere at the end", meaning a high number (such as the list size or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

If you are getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`, it's most likely because `listB` isn't mutable, so it won't support sorting in-place.